# Override "show" route of a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How to make the second route work?

```
resources :users, only: [:edit, :update]
get ':id', :to => 'users#show', :as =>'user'
```

Rails gives error because of the second line:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'user' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

Comment: Try switching the order of the routes to change their precedence.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Expanding my comment for reference of future viewers.)

Switching the order of the routes will change the precedence, giving the `get` route preference to the RESTful routes.

From the documentation in a new `config/routes.rb`:

```
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
```

Comment: Switching the order would make the resource's :index malfunction, because it matches the "get" line with an empty :id. Any solution to that?